# CodeIgniter: Как реализовать мультиязычность на сайте

Tags: база-данных, php, codeigniter

Имеются два языковых файла, имеются две таблицы одинаковые по содержанию, но на разных языках, которые содержат контент страницы.

Установил это: [URI Language Identifier](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/). По умолчанию стоит русский язык. Пользователем выбирается, например, английский язык по ссылке `http://сайт.com/en/`.
В куки записывается, что нужно смотреть папку языка english. Если выбирается `http://сайт.com/ru/`, то смотрится папка с русским языковым.

Главный вопрос в том, как заставить использовать эти куки en и ru для переключения подключения к таблице с соответствующими префиксами?

По умолчанию стоит таблица русского page. Например, если выбирается английский язык, то смотрится таблица с префиксом `en_`, то есть `en_page`.

Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Comment: рекомендую эту статью <br>
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev_for_dummies/130279/

Comment: Спасибо за старание помочь, но вопрос касается непосредственно фрэмворка CodeIgniter, а не отдельно самописных сайтов